# How to stop the page from redirecting to another page without the user action (StopPropogation) and window.oneforeunload event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

```
function confirmExit(e) {

var f = FormChanges();  //checking whether page has been modified or not    

if (f.length > 0){
    if (submitForm == false) {
        if(!e) var e = window.event;
        //e.cancelBubble for IE and it does work
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        e.returnValue = "You have made updates to this page which have not been saved.";
        //e.stopPropagation for Firefox doesn't work.
        if (e.stopPropagation) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }       
     }
     }
   setTimeout("enableBeforeUnloadHandler()", "100");
}

} //ignore this

 window.onbeforeunload=confirmExit;
 function enableBeforeUnloadHandler()
{
  window.onbeforeunload=confirmExit;
}
```

When the user wants to go to some other page without submitting the form in the current page,it prompts whether to leave the page or not?

But the problem is, it redirects to the other page in a couple of seconds without waiting for the user action at all,How do i fix this?
(I doesn't work in Firefox,in IE it works fine)

Answer (score 0):

Could be like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Are you sure you want to navigate away?";
}
```

You actually need to return `true` (change page) or `false` (stay on page).

Comment: Yeah,By using ConfirmExit I am doing that,But it's not at all waiting for the user action.

Comment: Your 'confirmExit()' function has to `return false` at the end. You are not returning anything.

Comment: Still no Luck it's redirecting to the other page without waiting for any user action.

Comment: I just tried deleting the whole of if( e.propagation) loop and added return false at it

Comment: Did you try my function just to see, if it does work after all?

Comment: I tried,no luck there! would you be kind enough to specifically tell me where to use your function(post the updated code here or something)?

Comment: Well, I was thinking about [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907(v=vs.85).aspx) but you are right, it does not work for me...at least in IE. strange. You should also look at jQuery, perhaps this approach is more cross browser compatible: [unload](https://api.jquery.com/unload/)

Comment: Tried almost everything,it just doesn't seem to work and I have no idea why?